# 2x2 contingency table, $d$ statistic?

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I am reading [The Fluctuating Female Vote: Politics, Religion, and the Ovulatory Cycle](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0956797612466416). (It shows up in several of Gelman's papers as an example of how not to do statistics.) Among the reported findings are a number of what seem to be chi-squared tests for independence using a 2x2 contingency table, for example:

> Women in relationships, however, were more likely to vote for Romney
> at if they were in the high- fertility group (M = 40.4%) than if they
> were in the low-fertility group (23.4%), $\chi^2(1, N = 134) = 4.44$, $p = .035$, $d = 0.37$.

I am curious about the last statistic, $d=0.37$. What is $d$ here, and how is it calculated?

Comment: The paper is behind a paywall and the supplemental materials provide no clarification.  One guess, though, is that $d$ *might* be Cohen's *d.*  Perhaps a search of the paper for "Cohen" would turn up an explanation.

Comment: @whuber I wondered about that, but Cohen's $d$ does not make sense to me in this case: the difference in means is 17%, and from $p=.035$ we can guess the standard error to be around 8%. So then $d$ would be about 2.1.

Comment: Isn't Cohen's *d* the difference in means divided by a pooled standard *deviation,* not standard error?

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. That explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The paper is available here. (I don't know if the authors have permission to post it.) [ResearchGate link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236277144_The_Fluctuating_Female_Vote)

Here's my conjecture about that *d* statistic:

Other places in the paper they report the *d* statistic when comparing two groups by *F*-test or *t*-test.

One possibility is that the statistic reported for the *chi-square* test is really a *phi* statistic, but it got changed to "*d*" during copyediting.

Another possibility is that they used some formula to convert *phi* to *d* so that the effect sizes would be on a uniform scale. (FYI: there's some discussion on that conversion here: [CrossValidated link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124105/how-do-i-convert-cramers-v-to-cohens-d) ).